# Angular 10 form action not getting variable

Tags: angular, forms, redirect, angular-forms

I am creating a form in angular, used from a 3rd party, which needs to redirect away from my site for a payment and back.

I have added their sample code (the form which does a post) into my angular app and added a formGroup, and an action to the form (the action is the url I want to redirect to).

```
<form [formGroup]="tdsvt" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit2021" method="post" id="redirectForm" action="{{redirectUrl}}"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="id" formControlName="reqID" /> 
</form>
```

I have changed the action to the variable that is needed, but it does not redirect and it stays blank.
I have tried doing a normal post request and subscribe like so:

```
return this.http.post<any>(redirectUrl, data);
```

But I am hit with a CORS issue as it is a total different URL.

How can I get the action to work as a variable and redirect? Or if I shouldn't use an action, what's the best method around this?

Thank you

Comment: If you need a regular form, you can add the ngNoForm attribute to the form. Not sure if formcontrols still work then though..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure if that works as the action is still not brining back the variable that I want :(